# OSX (El Capitan) - Homebrew Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM + mongoDB - Service unavailable

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, apache

**UPDATE**

I've tried using PhpMyAdmin with the same configuration and I've got the same error 503 Service Unavailable.
So **it seems that it has nothing to do with the mongodb** module but it's an Apache or PHP-FPM misconfiguration. In my opinion it's most probably the fcgi proxy which doesn't call php-fpm the proper way but I don't know what goes wrong.

**Original question**

I've been tearing my hair out for hours trying to find the a solution.

Config:

- OSX (El Capitan)
- homebrew Apache 2.4
- php-fpm (5.5 or 7.0, I've tried both, same error!)

This works in index.php

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
```

**Php info**

> PHP Version 7.0.18
>   MongoDB extension version 1.2.8

I've tried calling a php in a subdirectory (I suspected that there is a problem with the proxy parameter) but it's working.

Conslusion so far:

- apache is working
- document root OK
- default index OK (I've tried explicitly index.php anyway)
- php-fpm is running
- apache proxy to php-fpm working (see UPDATE above!)

**Now the weird part**

I change the contents of index.php to this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:3001");
```

The only composer module installed is mongodb/mongodb with `composer require mongodb/mongodb`

The result is simple `503 Service Unavailable`

The parameter (`mongodb://localhost:3001`) in irrelevant I have the same error without any parameters or with intentionally bad parameters.
(But in case you're wondering I'm trying to connect to the mongodb of a local development instance of a Meter application that's the reason for port 3001. And the connection is working from external program /Robomongo/)

Currently I'm using Apache `ProxyPassMatch` but I've tried `SetHandler` method as well (see below). I've tried with `php-fpm 5.5` and `php-fpm 7.0` (both installed with homebrew)

Apache config:

`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9007/Users/myuser/Projects/test/$1`

Or

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9007"
</FilesMatch>
```

No error messages in Apache or php-fpm logs (even with loglevel debug) despite error logging is working (I've tried making a deliberate PHP syntax error and it generated the proper error message in php-fpm error log file)
e.g.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader
$client = new MongoDB;
```

The error message is clearly shown so the error logging is fine

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB' not found in
>   /Users/myuser/Projects/test/index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /Users/myuser/Projects/test/index.php on line 17

I've tried connecting to a MySQL database with this code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");
print_r($res);
```

It works like a charm.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
composer.json contents as requested by a comment

```
{
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you connect to Mongo directly? Is it even running?

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger Yes, as I've mentioned: "And the connection is working from external program /Robomongo/)"

Comment: Could you post your composer.json file

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger sure, I've added to the question. As you can see this is a completely empty test project. Nothing else in it just what I said. 3 lines of PHP and one composer module.

Comment: Maybe try to open an issue on their github page?

Comment: If the question isn't getting enough attention here

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger Thanks for the suggestion. I've narrowed down the problem to Apache and php-fpm configuration see the update section

Comment: Why not just run PHP with MAMP

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this? I'm having similar issues on a mysql db with Magento 2.  I believe this is an Apache and php-fpm issue.  Also using homebrew.  My proxypass match is identical to yours.